# Google Chrome refuses to connect to domain resolving to 127.0.0.1

Tags: macos, google-chrome, localhost

I have a very weird problem with Google Chrome. I have a Vagrant setup that runs several sites, with different hostnames, all on port 8080. I.e. I have a site that is named `test1.local.testnetwork.net`, `test2.local.testnetwork.net`, etc. All these domain names resolve to `127.0.0.1`. I can access them from Firefox and Safari just fine as `http://test1.local.testnetwork.net:8080/`, `http://test2.local.testnetwork.net:8080/` etc. However, from Google Chrome I can access only `http://localhost:8080/`, but not any of the domains above. Trying to access them produces ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. I checked proxy settings and there are none. Command-line access (e.g. curl) also works fine - only Chrome has problems. Any ideas why Chrome may be refusing to connect to these domains?

This is on Mac OS X 10.9.5.

Comment: Have you actually registered those domain names (test1.local.testnetwork.net, etc.) with a domain registrar?

Comment: @kittykittybangbang Yes, they resolve through public DNS (to 127.0.0.1 of course).

Comment: Is it possibly ignoring your hosts file? Have a look at this to see if that helps: http://superuser.com/questions/648133/why-is-chrome-ignoring-etc-hosts-on-os-x

Comment: @MhluziBhaka the domains are not in hosts file, they are resolved via public DNS.

Comment: Actually, after I added them to /etc/hosts Chrome connects to them now.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable to Built-in Asynchronous DNS, which should all local domains tone accessed.

Go to chrome://flags and set "Built-in Asynchronous DNS" to "Disabled", then restart the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to chrome://flags but unfortunately for me it does not have any mention of "Built-in Asynchronous DNS".